# Simple way to create a folder when nautilus file list is full of items

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, directory

It is a question of Nautilus file manager of Ubuntu 18.04. Is there a simple way to create a Folder when file list is full of items?

Comment: Can you clarify a little - what list and what does ot have to do with creating a folder?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I've added the necessary detail to explain the OP's question as it's a feature that disappeared a few revisions ago and I've been meaning to complain about it also.  I work in list mode all day, so it's super-annoying!

Answer (score 9):

It has always been in the application menu, but it's been turned into an icon:

[image: Application menu with New Folder icon highlighted]

There is, of course, the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> but some of us aren't always on a physical keyboard these days.

Comment: "the "New folder" is *only* in the Right-click menu in vacant space in Icon mode..." this is not true, you can simply use the [create new folder button](https://askubuntu.com/a/1062505/480481).

Comment: @pomsky I stand corrected! My bad.  I have adjusted my answer.  Funny how you can look at these things all day and not see it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using Nautilus default shortcuts?

-New folder is:  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

You can see all the shortcuts and configure them here->

[image: Here in this image]

Comment: As already mentioned in my answer, this doesn't work particularly well when you don't have a physical keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Click the "hamburger" menu button (three horizontal bars or dots) at the top right. A dialog should pop up. Click the button with "create new folder" symbolic icon.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yet another keyboard-only option, besides the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> hotkey, is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> followed by <kbd>f</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> shows you the same right-click menu you get when right-clicking an empty space in the file manager.

It appears indeed to be impossible to get to that menu with a mouse right-click when the list is full.

Answer (score 0):

If Nautilus has the same features as most file managers, then a right-click in the window (not over a file or folder, in a maximized window you should have cursor to the right end of the window). That should show a menu that will include 'create folder'. Choosing this feature will then give you a dialog where you would name the folder. Clicking 'OK' or 'create' will then create the folder for you. Authentication may be required - enter password when asked.

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately.  I'll update the OPs question as this is a little bugbear of mine, too.